# How to manipulate Kafka key documents with KSQLDB?

Tags: ksqldb

I have a problem. I can't find a way to create a stream by filtering on the key of a kafka document.

I would like to filter and manipulate the json of a kafka key to retrieve the `payload` of the following example which corresponds to my couchbase id:

> ksql> print 'cb_bench_products-get_purge' limit 1;

```
Key format: JSON or HOPPING(KAFKA_STRING) or TUMBLING(KAFKA_STRING) or KAFKA_STRING
Value format: JSON or KAFKA_STRING

rowtime: 2022/03/04 10:49:43.643 Z, key: {"schema":{"type":"string","optional":false},"payload":"history::05000228023411_RO_RO11219082::80"}, value: {[...]}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify the `value` part of your message so I've mocked up some data and assumed that it's also JSON. First I load it into a topic to test again:

```sh
$ kcat -b localhost:9092 -t test -P -K!
{"schema":{"type":"string","optional":false},"payload":"history::05000228023411_RO_RO11219082::80"}!{"col1":"foo","col2":"bar","col3":42}
^D
```

Check the data in the topic using ksqlDB (0.23.1-rc9):

```sql
ksql> print 'test' from beginning;
Key format: JSON or SESSION(KAFKA_STRING) or HOPPING(KAFKA_STRING) or TUMBLING(KAFKA_STRING) or KAFKA_STRING
Value format: JSON or KAFKA_STRING
rowtime: 2022/03/04 14:14:01.539 Z, key: {"schema":{"type":"string","optional":false},"payload":"history::05000228023411_RO_RO11219082::80"}, value: {"col1":"foo","col2":"bar","col3":42}, partition: 0
```

Declare a stream over the topic, using a `STRUCT` to represent the nested JSON. I'm assuming you are not interested in the `schema` so I've omitted that.

```sql
CREATE STREAM my_test (
  my_key_col STRUCT < payload VARCHAR > KEY,
  col1 VARCHAR,
  col2 VARCHAR,
  col3 INT
) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC = 'test', FORMAT = 'JSON');
```

Query the stream with a predicate on the key:

```sql
SET 'auto.offset.reset' = 'earliest';

SELECT my_key_col->payload, col1, col2, col3
  FROM my_test
 WHERE my_key_col->payload LIKE 'history%'
EMIT CHANGES;

+--------------------------------------------+-------+------+-------+
|PAYLOAD                                     |COL1   |COL2  |COL3   |
+--------------------------------------------+-------+------+-------+
|history::05000228023411_RO_RO11219082::80   |foo    |bar   |42     |
```

Comment: On StackOverflow you should amend your original question with further details, not post it as an answer.

Comment: When you do `CREATE STREAM… AS` you don't specify the schema. The schema is implicit in the `SELECT` columns.

Comment: Ok thanks ! I deleted my answer, sorry.